# Slack Application, pushing new modal based on selected option

Tags: python, slack

I currently have my application to open a modal when a global shortcut is used. The modal opens and I am presented with 3 options. I was able to get it to push a new modal when any of the options were selected, but now I am stuck on how to open different modals based on the user response. Right now the code does not interpret which was selected, and just that an actionId-0 took place. I guess I am not really sure at the next steps. Do I need to utilize @app.view in order to read the submission payload?

Open on shortcut:

```
def open_modal(ack, shortcut, client):
    # Acknowledge the shortcut request
    ack()
    # Call the views_open method using the built-in WebClient
    client.views_open(
        trigger_id=shortcut["trigger_id"],
        # A simple view payload for a modal
        view={
            "title": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "#Tech Request"
            },
            "submit": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Submit"
            },
            "type": "modal",
            "close": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Cancel"
            },
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "actions",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "static_select",
                            "placeholder": {
                                "type": "plain_text",
                                "text": "Select an issue type"
                            },
                            "options": [
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "type": "plain_text",
                                        "text": "Account Issues"
                                    },
                                    "value": "value-0"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "type": "plain_text",
                                        "text": "M1"
                                    },
                                    "value": "value-1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "type": "plain_text",
                                        "text": "M2"
                                    },
                                    "value": "value-2"
                                }
                            ],
                            "action_id": "actionId-0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    )
```

Open when any option is selected:

```
def update_modal(ack, body, client):
    # Acknowledge the button request
    ack()
    # Call views_update with the built-in client
    client.views_update(
        # Pass the view_id
        view_id=body["view"]["id"],
        # String that represents view state to protect against race conditions
        hash=body["view"]["hash"],
        # View payload with updated blocks
        view={
            "title": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Account Issue Request"
            },
            "submit": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Submit"
            },
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": "This is a link to a confluence page"
                    },
                    "accessory": {
                        "type": "button",
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Click Me",
                        },
                        "value": "click_me_123",
                        "url": "https://google.com",
                        "action_id": "button-action"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "input",
                    "element": {
                        "type": "plain_text_input",
                        "action_id": "plain_text_input-action"
                    },
                    "label": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "SFDC Contact ID:",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "input",
                    "element": {
                        "type": "plain_text_input",
                        "action_id": "plain_text_input-action"
                    },
                    "label": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Describe the issue",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "input",
                    "element": {
                        "type": "multi_users_select",
                        "placeholder": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Tag related people",
                        },
                        "action_id": "multi_users_select-action"
                    },
                    "label": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Tag related people",
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type": "modal"
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you have to take care of on the backend. I found that the easiest way to do this is to parse the payload received and send back a modal based on that